# push / slide transition with react navigation

Tags: react-navigation

I'm trying to work out the best way to create a horizontal slide transition using react navigation.

I'm using the stackNavigator and the default IOS transition appears like it is "stacking over the top" of each previous view
[like this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4cw6.gif) where as I'm trying to have the transition Push the previous view and slide out like [this push slide example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nim1W.gif).

Is there a simple config setting I'm missing? Or does this effect require a custom transition to be created?

Comment: I'm looking for this as well - a true 'push' instead of a 'slide over'....I'm also using the UINavigationController.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?